# Maven no dependency folder in target folder. Unable to access jetty-runner.jar

Tags: java, maven, heroku, jetty, war

I am building a project using Vaadin which uses .WAR files.
The Project runs perfectly on localhost when I run `package` and then `jetty:run` in Intelij.
I tried to push the project to a Heroku server following Heroku's instructions of having:

`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war`

in the Procfile. When I try to start the server I get the error message:
`Error: Unable to access jarfile target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar`
 This error makes sense because I don't even see a dependency directory in my target directory nor a jetty-runner.jar anywhere else in my project.

I am quite new to Maven so I might be missing a step. Do I need to do something to create the dependency directory?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The below links should solve your issue:

[Heroku unable to access jetty-runner jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888614/heroku-unable-to-access-jetty-runner-jar-file)

[Why can't my jar files and my .war file be found within my project build? Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260293/why-cant-my-jar-files-and-my-war-file-be-found-within-my-project-build-maven)

Best of luck.